# Report Builder и MySql

Tags: mysql

Интересует вопрос, работает ли Report Builder с бд MySQL?

Comment: rdl принимает же DataTable. Преобразовать - и должно пойти.

Comment: @nick_n_a не совсем понятно, что значить преобразовать? Что в что преобразовать?

Comment: `ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("name", source)` ,  Здесь source может быть как `List<>` так и DataTable. Считать базу, преобразовать и всё.

Comment: Уточните язык или технологию, то я вам пишу с использыванием с# библиотеки. С# - крос-платформа, ей впринципе в 99% всёравно какая субд, лишь бы драйвер к ней был. Есть же ещё Report-Server, подключать его к MySql не пробовал.

Comment: @nick_n_a если я не ошибаюсь Вы описали как делается в reportviewer в студии c#. Я имел ввиду саму программу report builder 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/139dc565-a098-4720-910d-55c308235d42/create-a-report-using-report-builder-30-and-mysql-as-database?forum=sqlreportingservices). драйвера необходимо ставить исключительно под тем пользователем под кем будет разрабатываться отчет, иначе report builder не будет видеть при создание источника данных mysql прописанный в ODBC.